# Twitter Bootstrap Stacking Hierarchy using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

This is my layout in desktop

```
   |   Content     |   | Sidebar |
```

And i wanted to acheive this in responsive mobile

```
|  Sidebar  |
|  Content  |
```

I am using Hubspot to create the website and i dont have prevelidge to write pull-right and pull-left classes on span, so can you guyz let me know to do this in `jQuery` or `javascript` as i am not the master in javascript

Comment: Any code to work with?

Comment: Why are you not using the default grid options? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with jQuery .before()...

https://api.jquery.com/before/

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $( "#content" ).before( $( "#sidebar" ) );
    }
});
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

You could also do it with .prependTo()...

https://api.jquery.com/prependTo/

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $('.blog-sidebar').prependTo( $('.blog-sidebar').parent() );
    } else {
        $('.blog-sidebar').appendTo( $('.blog-sidebar').parent() );
    }
});
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

In your situation, you'd probably be better using the prependTo method with `$('.blog-sidebar')`

Comment: You need to take a little step towards helping us help you, I sure as hell don't want to go fishing through all of your code. You should be able to apply one of the method's I have given above to your code.

Comment: Thanks for your help +1, i will try the code and let you knw